# How to use HTML5 color picker in Django admin

Tags: python, django, html

I'm trying to implement the HTML5 colorpicker in Django's admin page.

Here is my model:

```
#model.py
...

class Category(models.Model):
    ...
    color = models.CharField(max_length=7)
```

Here is the form:

```
#form.py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms.widgets import TextInput
from .models import Category

class CategoryForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'color': TextInput(attrs={'type': 'color'}),
        }

class CategoryAdminForm(ModelForm):
    form = CategoryForm
```

And finally the admin:

```
#admin.py
...
from .forms import CategoryAdminForm

...
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form_class = CategoryAdminForm
    filter_horizontal = ('questions',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': (('name', 'letter'), 'questions', 'color')
            }),
        )
```

However, the type for the field is still text. How do I change the type for the input field to color in the admin page?

Answer (score 46):

I found the answer in the documentation:

The extra class in forms.py was not necessary

```
#form.py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms.widgets import TextInput
from .models import Category

class CategoryForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'color': TextInput(attrs={'type': 'color'}),
        }
```

And in the admin:

```
#admin.py
...
from .forms import CategoryForm

...
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CategoryForm
    filter_horizontal = ('questions',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': (('name', 'letter'), 'questions', 'color')
            }),
        )
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use this library 
https://github.com/jaredly/django-colorfield

**Installation:**

- Run `pip install django-colorfield`
- Add `colorfield` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`
- Collect static files with `./manage.py collectstatic`

**Usage:**

In your models, you can use it like this:

```
from django.db import models
from colorfield.fields import ColorField

class MyModel(model.Model):

     color = ColorField(default='#FF0000')
```

Comment: Can't get this to work (does not display field). I'm using this in a `forms.Form` and not a `model.Model`, is this why? Is there a way to only use it in a form?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add a color picker to a `forms.Form` rather than a `model.Model` this would be the way to go:

```py
from django import forms

class GaeParamsForm(forms.Form):
    hex_color = forms.CharField(label='hex_color', max_length=7,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'color'}))
    font_size = forms.IntegerField(label='font_size', 
        min_value=1, max_value=400)
```

This essentially writes the type attribute of the input HTML tag, i.e.

```
<input id="id_hex_color" maxlength="7" name="hex_color" type="color">
```

You will receive the data as hex string with # sign e.g. `#ff0000`.