# How to use django-colorfield in a forms.py file in django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use [Django-colorfield](https://pypi.org/project/django-colorfield/) to create a drop-down from which a color can be selected. However, the priority section in the output just says **<colorfield.fields.ColorField>**.I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39859224/how-to-use-html5-color-picker-in-django-admin) but it didn't work. [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aTiX.png), Code:

```
#models.py

from django.db import models
from colorfield.fields import ColorField

class Todo(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    COLOR_CHOICES = [
        ("#8b0000", "red"),
        ("#ffff00", "yellow"),
        ("#006400","green")
    ]

    priority = ColorField(choices=COLOR_CHOICES)
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

```
#forms.py
from django import forms 
from colorfield.fields import ColorField
from .models import Todo


class TodoForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(max_length=40,
    
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Enter todo here', 'aria-label' : 'Todo', 'aria-describedby' : 'add-btn'}))


    COLOR_CHOICES = [
        ("#8b0000", "red"),
        ("#ffff00", "yellow"),
        ("#006400","green")
    ]

    priority = ColorField(choices=COLOR_CHOICES)
```

Comment: The colorfield is only available in django admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ColorField only works in Django Admin. If you would like a colorpicker in your template, I would suggest creating CharField, like:

```
priority = models.CharField(max_length=7)
```

Add in your template add either a JS plugin for showing a colorpicker or use the HTML5 colorpicker, for example:

```
<input id="id_priority" maxlength="7" name="priority" type="color">
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the colorpicker from [django-colorfield](https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/django-colorfield) in your templates (outside of Django admin) you just have to set the field to type `CharField` and pass the widget [ColorWidget](https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/django-colorfield/blob/master/colorfield/widgets.py) to it. That's it.

For your case that would be something like this:

```
class TodoForm(forms.Form):
    COLOR_CHOICES = ['#8b0000', '#ffff00', '#006400']
    text = forms.CharField(max_length=40, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter todo here', 'aria-label': 'Todo', 'aria-describedby': 'add-btn'}))
    priority = ColorField(widget=ColorWidget(attrs={'palette': COLOR_CHOICES}))
```

Note that you have to pass the `COLOR_CHOICES` as list as well as attribute to the `ColorWidget` with the key `palette` in order to have the color palette.

Answer (score 0):

color=forms.CharField(max_length=7,widget=TextInput(attrs={"type": "color", }))

this works form well.

Answer (score 0):

by fallowing @Smort solution, I figured out that colorfield works by default in frontend (template) we just need to as necessary  javascript files to the template.

in model I have:

header_color = ColorField(default='#FF0000')

and I use ModelForm with just defined fields, nothing else is needed

```html
In forms.py
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['header_color',]
        labels = {
            'header_color': 'My color',
        }
In template:
<!--    Colorfield-->
   <script src="{% static 'colorfield/jscolor/jscolor.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'colorfield/colorfield.js' %}"></script>
```